# Java: Convert List of Object to Set of Map

Tags: java

Say I have a list of of Objects (say `List<User>`), something like

```
[
    {
        "name": "myName",
        "age": 1,
        "someField": "foo"
    },
    {
        "name": "otherName",
        "age": 2,
        "someField": "bar"
    },
]
```

I want to convert this to `Set<Map<String, Integer>>` such that I get a set of `name => age` pair. So final result should be `[{"myName": 1},{"otherName": 2}]`

How can I use the stream and collector to do this?

Comment: curious why a `Set<Map<String, Integer>>` rather than just a `Map<String, Integer>?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Maybe there can be duplicate names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
final List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
users.add(user1);
users.add(user2);
users.add(user3);


Set<Map<String, Integer>> usersSet = 
    users
        .stream()
        .map(u -> Collections.singletonMap(u.getName(), u.getAge()))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below piece of code for parsing JSON String and then doing some manipulation with that :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    String str = "[     {         \"name\": \"myName\",         \"age\": 1,         \"someField\": \"foo\"     },     {         \"name\": \"otherName\",         \"age\": 2,         \"someField\": \"bar\"     }, ]";
    JSONArray jsonobj = new JSONArray(str);
    Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); 
    for(int i = 0;i<jsonobj.length();i++){
        JSONObject obj = jsonobj.getJSONObject(i);
        map.put(obj.getString("name"), obj.getInt("age"));
    }
    Set<Map<String,Integer>> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(map);
    System.out.println(set);
}
```

Library used : **org.json**

Answer (score -1):

Here is a possible conversion to `Map<String, Integer>` with duplicate handling:

```
final List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
users.add(new User("name 1", 25));
users.add(new User("name 1", 49));
users.add(new User("name 2", 67));

final Map<String, Integer> nameToAge = users.stream().collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                        user -> user.name, 
                        user -> user.age, 
                        (user1, user2) -> {
                            System.out.println("Resolving duplicates...");
                            return user1;
                        })
                );
```

In this case the definition for type `User` is:

```
public class User {
    public final String name;
    public final int age;

    public User(final String name, final int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not looking for `Map<String, Integer>` Looking for `Set<Map<String, Integer>>`

Comment: @Kousha it's rather peculiar to need a set of maps where each map has only a single pair... Perhaps you're interested in a set of tuples (pairs)? However, it would then be better to model tuples with some sort of type `Pair` instead of using `Map` with a single element for this. Please note that just having an instance of `Map` already provides you with a guarantee that there will be no duplicates, which I'm guessing is the reason for using `Set`.